# Adding 90° to atan2 result

Tags: vectors, pi

I have a question since im using Atan2 that correctly results in -pi/pi

problem is the object that im using the rotation on has its source rotation at -90 
so for it to work coorecly i wanna continously add 90° to the result

problem is that Atan2 results in ranges  0 180  / -0 -180 that is fine cause the game im using them on uses it exacly like that 
But i have no idea how to continously add 90° but staying within the ranges

so 180 doesnt result in 270  etc

How to correctly add 90° without going out on original range ?

Example 
Atan2 result = 180 should retrun -90 
Atan2 result = -0 should return 90
Atan2 result = 90 should return 180

how am I to create a calculation to meet these requirements ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please proofread your post and edit it accordingly.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to add 90 but still have the range be $[-180,180)$?

Comment: yes this is exacly what i want

Answer (score 2):

Instead of computing $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$, use
$\operatorname{atan2}(x,-y)$ instead.

(I'm assuming that you are using an $\operatorname{atan2}$ that takes the $y$
parameter first, adjust accordingly.)

To see why this works, look at the point $(x,y)$ in the complex plane, that is
$x+ iy$. Rotating by 90° corresponds to multiplying by $i$, so we get
$-y+ix$.